# How can I search for a line then replace a line that comes after

Tags: python, python-2.7

I have a text file that I need to replace a line of text

its a very large file so reading the whole file into memory is not the best way for this.
there are tons of these blocks of code here is just two to get an idea.
what i need to do is replace `'const/4 v0, 0x1'` with `'const/4 v0, 0x0'`
but i need to only replace the one that is in the `canCancelFocus()Z` method
so i need to search for the line `'.method public static canCancelFocus()Z'`
then replace the `'const/4 v0, 0x1'` with the `'const/4 v0, 0x0'` with in that method.

Textfile.text contains:

```
.method public static CancelFocus()Z
    .locals 1

    const/4 v0, 0x1

    return v0
.end method

.method public static FullSize()Z
    .locals 1

    const/4 v0, 0x1

    return v0
.end method 

......
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's some code for ya:

```
fp = open("Textfile.text", "r+")

inFunc = False
line = fp.readline()
while line is not None:
    if inFunc and "const/4 v0, 0x1" in line:
        line = line.replace("0x1", "0x0")
        fp.seek(-len(line), 1)
        fp.write(line)
    elif ".method public static canCancelFocus()Z" in line:
        inFunc = True
    elif ".end method" in line:
        inFunc = False
    line = fp.readline()

fp.close()
```

Comment: Right, I jump between languages a lot and I forgot the and thing. Anyways, this is just an example. Ill edit it to not load the whole file in memory.

Comment: first one worked fine but it was reading the whole text file into memory. the text file has 1500+ lines so im not sure if that is too much to read into memory or not. the second one just hangs and doesn't do anything. also this will have to be run many times so im not sure what the best way to go about it is.

Comment: `for line in fp` would be more pythonic than a while loop. Also, the continue will cause the loop to go back up without reading a new line, and is otherwise not necessary.

Comment: Yeah, but I didn't know if you could edit that line and have it be saved back into the file.

Answer (score 1):

You need to use a flag to toggle when to do your replacements; you set it when you have seen the `.method` line and you reset it again when you a `.end method` is seen.

Then you only look for the line to fix when your context flag is True:

```
with open('textfile.text', 'r+') as tfile:
    incontext = False
    pos = 0
    for line in tfile:
        pos += len(line) # The read-ahead buffer means we can't use relative seeks.

        # Toggle context
        if line.strip().startswith('.method'):
            incontext = True
            continue
        if line.strip().startswith('.end method'):
            incontext = False
            continue

        if incontext and 'const/4 v0, 0x1' in line:
            line = line.replace('0x1', '0x0')
            tfile.seek(pos - len(line))
            tfile.write(line)
```

Note that the above overwrites the file in-place; this only works when your replacements are exactly the same length as the replaced text.

If your going to change the length of the lines (shorter, longer) you need to write this to a new file (or `sys.stdout`):

```
with open('textfile.text', 'r') as tfile:
    with open('outputfile.text', 'w') as output:
        incontext = False
        for line in tfile:
            # Toggle context
            if line.strip().startswith('.method'):
                incontext = True
            if line.strip().startswith('.end method'):
                incontext = False

            if incontext and 'const/4 v0, 0x1' in line:
                line = line.replace('0x1', '0x0')

            # Write every line to the output file
            output.write(line)
```